# How can I show element's index number from a given list on hover in matplotlib graph in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, mplcursors

I am using **`mplcursors`** module to show label value. I also want to show the index number from given lists for that particular point on which I will hover.
My Example Code snippet:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mplcursors
lines = plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 4, 6, 10])
plt.ylabel('some numbers')
mplcursors.cursor(hover=True)
plt.show()
```

Is there any way that I can use the `mplcursors` to annotate the required information(as its easy)?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mplcursors` allows to specify a function that is called every time just before an annotation is shown. That function gets a parameter `sel` which among others has a `target` field. In case of a "line", apart from the xy value, the target contains an `index`.  The integer part of the `index` is an index into the `x` and `y` arrays of the left end of the segment the cursor is on.  The fractional part of the `index` tells how far we are between the left and the right end of the segment.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mplcursors

def show_annotation(sel):
    ind = int(sel.target.index)
    frac = sel.target.index - ind
    x, y = sel.target
    sel.annotation.set_text(f'left index:{ind} frac:{frac:.2f}\nx:{x:.2f} y:{y:.2f}')

lines = plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 4, 6, 10])
plt.ylabel('some numbers')
cursor = mplcursors.cursor(hover=True)
cursor.connect("add", show_annotation)
plt.show()
```

[image: example annotation]

Comment: I really appreciate your answer. Thanks